# Splitting string with regex and re.findall

Tags: python, regex, string

I want to match any number of digits, decimal points, and the letter e, or  ONE CHARACTER in this list of characters when it occurs in a string:
`+ - % ^ * / ( )`
then I want to break the subject string into a list containing each individual match.

I have the following Regex to attempt to accomplish this, which I'm fairly certain it does correctly: `([0-9.e]+|[\^\*\/\%\+\-\(\)])` I even went on regex101.com and tested it, and it properly matches how I want it to:

[image]

However, when I run `re.findall()` on the following string `(5+2)*5` it returns me the following list:

```
['(', '5', '+', '2', u')*', '5']
```

What is wrong with my regex?

Comment: I can't reproduce your output, I get `['(', '5', '+', '2', ')', '*', '5']` as expected. Can you provide a [mcve]? What's your python version?

Comment: Ahh. It works for me now. The reason it didn't work is because I had a `.$` at the end of the second alternative